# bootstrap-datetimepicker: display value of input

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, eonasdan-datetimepicker

How can I persuade the datetimepicker to display its value in the input text field at initial pageload?

In this case the value attribute of the datepicker text-input is already set, but the field is displayed blank. Therefore I've tried to set the 'data-date-defaultdate' attribute but at the initial pageload the text field´s still blank. After a reload the value is displayed as expected.

The Form (excerpt):

```
<form name="news" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label required" for="news_validFrom">Start time</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
            <div class="input-group date datetime-picker" id="datetime1">
                <input type="text" id="news_validFrom" name="news[validFrom]" required="required" class="form-control" value="2016-07-08T00:00:00+02:00" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
                </span>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label required" for="news_validTo">End date</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
            <div class="input-group date date-picker" id="datetime2">
                <input type="text" id="news_validTo" name="news[validTo]" required="required" class="form-control" value="2016-06-22T00:00:00+02:00" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
                </span>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
// [...]
</form>
```

The Script:

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetime1')
    .attr('data-date-defaultdate', $('#datetime1 input').attr('value'))
    .datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD MMM YYYY HH:mm',
        defaultDate: $('#datetime1 input').attr('value'),
        viewDate: 'true'
    });
    $('#datetime2')
    .attr('data-date-defaultdate', $('#datetime2 input').attr('value'))
    .datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD MMM YYYY HH:mm',
        defaultDate: $('#datetime2 input').attr('value')
    });
});
```

Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: Please, add your code to JSFiddle

Comment: New Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s2hc3ryn/2/

Answer (score 1):

Chnage to:

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetime1')
    .attr('data-date-defaultdate', $('#datetime1 input').val())
    .datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD MMM YYYY HH:mm',
        defaultDate: $('#datetime1 input').val(s),
        viewDate: 'true'
    });
    $('#datetime2')
    .attr('data-date-defaultdate', $('#datetime2 input').val())
    .datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD MMM YYYY HH:mm',
        defaultDate: $('#datetime2 input').val()
    });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not the trick. This way the input is also blank after a reload.

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn´t come to a solution for this problem I gave another fork of the bootstrap-datetimepicker a try: [smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker)

This one works as expected and I don´t have the problem with the input value (the value is always displayed in the text field).
I suppose, the problem could issue from the given date format (value="2016-07-0 **8T** 00:00:00 **+02:00**"), but I haven´t figure it out exactly.